# parser with integer literals

Tags: java, parsing, integer, lexical

I am looking for an easy and efficient way to implement a set of numbers in a lexical parser in java.            For example my input code is as follows :

```
"6+9" ,
```

the output would have to be a little like this :

```
   Number : 6   
   Sign : +   
   Number: 9
```

The issue I have is i have no way to recognize the number other than to implement it as follows :

```
static char INTVALUE = ('0') ;
```

which means I would have to manually enter each number from 0 to 9 and I don't know If such a method would even allows to have a number such as 85 in my input .

This is for a homework assignment by the way
Thanks .

Comment: You want to check if a `char` is a digit? [`Character#isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

Comment: If it's your homework, you are asked to do it to *learn something* from it, and you don't learn if you copy someones code. Do yourself a favour, *do it yourself*

Comment: I actually already completed the assignment, I am just looking for more efficient way to parse a number , the issue I have is I cannot parse a number greater than 9 . The last assignment I was able to implement a integer literal in EBNF using tokens, just would like to do the same in java . @August , i like the idea , would require me to create another class tho , which would make me have to check everything time if the char parsed is in fact a number or a sign.

Comment: For ASCII/Unicode (and not any weird character set) a character is a number if it's `>= 0` and `<= 9`.  For weird character sets you can use `isDigit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont use regular expressions for this. It sounds a best fit for what you are attempting to do.

Its fairly simple to learn. Look at Character classes (\d) and Quatifiers(+ ?) in this [cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

To check for integers and doubles us the following.

```
aStr.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
```

For just integers:

```
aStr.matches("-?\\d+");
```

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest grammars you can indeed use regular expressions:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
// ...
String expression = "(10+9)*2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d+|\\D)\\s*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String token = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.printf("%s: '%s'%n", 
        token.matches("\\d+") ? "Number" : "Symbol", 
        token);
}
```

In a compiler construction course you will probably be expected to construct an [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) and then transform that into a minimal DFA by implementing an algorithm like [this one](http://condor.depaul.edu/glancast/444class/docs/nfa2dfa.html). In real life you would normally use a tool like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or [JLex](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/current/manual.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something simple like this:

```
public List<Token> lex(String s) {
    List<Token> result = new ArrayList<Token>();

    int pos = 0;
    int len = s.length();
    while (pos < len) {
        switch (s.charAt(pos)) {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            {
                int end = pos;
                do {
                    ++end;
                } while (end < len && s.charAt(end) >= '0' && s.charAt(end) <= '9');

                result.add(new Number(s.substring(pos, end)));
                pos = end;
                break;
            }
        case '+':
            {
                result.add(new Operator("+"));
                ++pos;
                break;
            }
        // ...
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```